# PDF for zero point of random function

Tags: path-integral, stochastic-processes, randomness

Let us suppose a complex random function $\displaystyle \Psi (\mathbf{x})$ and its complex conjugate $\displaystyle \Psi ^{*}(\mathbf{x})$. We assume that these functions possess gaussian statistics, so that mean value of some functional $\displaystyle f\left[ \Psi ,\Psi ^{*}\right]$ shall be calculated as
\begin{equation*}
\langle f\rangle =\dfrac{\int D\Psi ^{*} D\Psi \ f\left[ \Psi ,\Psi ^{*}\right] \ \exp\left[ -\int \mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{x} \ \Psi ^{*}\hat{K} \Psi \right]}{\int D\Psi ^{*} D\Psi \ \exp\left[ -\int \mathrm{d}^{n}\mathbf{x} \ \Psi ^{*}\hat{K} \Psi \right]}
\end{equation*}
Here $\hat{K}$ is some differential operator.

**The question**: if I know for certain, that for the function $\displaystyle \Psi (\mathbf{x})$ there is such a point $\displaystyle \mathbf{y}$, that $\displaystyle \Psi (\mathbf{y}) =0$, how can I calculate a probability distibustion function for  $\displaystyle \mathbf{y}$? Shall it be

\begin{equation*}
P(\mathbf{y}) =\langle \delta ( \Re \Psi (\mathbf{y})) \cdotp \delta ( \Im \Psi (\mathbf{y})) \rangle 
\end{equation*}
or something else?

Thank everybody in advance! The question may seem a little bit mathematical, but I suppose, that physicists are more familiar with path integral, etc.

Comment: Have a look at https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.24.2760 and https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.96.022135

Comment: Although I'm not sure I understood what you want to compute.. You assume that for certain $y$ the field satisfies $\psi(y)=0$, but then ask for a probability distribution of this point?

Comment: @pp.ch.te yes, that is exactly what I mean. Thank you for the literature!

Comment: I must be missing something. If the point at which the field vanishes is some fixed $y_0$, for example it is the point $y_0=1$, isn't its pdf simply $P(y)=\delta(y-1)$ (or $\delta(y-y_0)$ in general)? Or, what you mean, is that each configuration of the field has some point $y$ in which always vanishes, although this point is not fixed but it follows some probability distribution $P(y)$ and you want to extract it by taking an average somehow?

Comment: In any case, you can constrain the field to having a specific value at some point by inserting a $\delta$-function. For example the probability density functional of a field that is constrained to be 10 in $x=3$ is $P[\phi] \propto \exp\left(-\phi K \phi\right)\delta\left(\phi(3)-10\right)$ (taking a scalar field for simplicity)

Comment: @pp.ch.te I mean your second claim. For some reason I know, that there must be a point, where $\Psi$ is zero, and this point is not fixed due to the stochastic nature of the problem. Thank you once again, the second paper you've sent is exactly what I need.

Comment: No problem. If think the question you pose is an interesting one, consider answering this question yourself if you find out...